# JTable: Remove border around cell when clearing row selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` and want to allow deselecting all rows by clicking into an empty part of the table. This works fine so far. However, even though I call `table.clearSelection();` the table still shows a border around the previously enabled cell (see cell **5** in the example):

[image: Table deselection issue]

I would like to get rid of this border as well (it looks especially out of place on the Mac's native look and feel, where the cells suddenly turn black).

Fully working minimal example code:

```
public class JTableDeselect extends JFrame {
    public JTableDeselect() {
        Object rowData[][] = { { "1", "2", "3" }, { "4", "5", "6" } };
        Object columnNames[] = { "One", "Two", "Three" };
        JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint()) == -1) {
                    table.clearSelection();
                }
            }
        });
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        setSize(300, 150);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        new JTableDeselect().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[edit] Tried to add `table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().clearSelection();` which was mentioned here around. But this does not help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Tried to add table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

The `table.clearSelection()` method invokes that method and the `clearSelection()` method of the `TableColumnModel`.

In addition to clearing the selection you also need to reset the "anchor and lead" indexes of the selection model:

```
table.clearSelection();

ListSelectionModel selectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
selectionModel.setAnchorSelectionIndex(-1);
selectionModel.setLeadSelectionIndex(-1);

TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
columnModel.getSelectionModel().setAnchorSelectionIndex(-1);
columnModel.getSelectionModel().setLeadSelectionIndex(-1);
```

Now if you use the arrow keys the focus will go to (0, 0), so you do lose the information about the last cell that was clicked.

If you only clear the selection model, then you will lose the row information but the column information will remain.

Experiment with clearing one or both of the models to get the effect you desire.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem: your table cell still has focus even though the selection is lost and so it draws itself showing this by showing a thickened border. Knowing 
one possible solution is to create your own renderer that removes a cell's focus when the cell loses selection. For example:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (!isSelected) {
            hasFocus = false;
        }
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple and effective!

Comment: @qqilihq, this assumes all data in the table uses the same renderer. For a more general solution, in addition to clearing the selection, you need to reset the anchor/lead indexes of the selection model. Then you don't need a custom renderer.

Comment: @camickr Great. This is approach is even more consistent. It also solves the case, that hitting a key after the deselection would jump back to the previously selected cell using above's solution. I've switched the "accepted" tag to your answer, as it's more complete and universal. Anyways, thank you for the initial pointer, Hovercraft!

Comment: @qqilihq: You were appropriate in changing the accepted answer to camickr.